# HTTP request beforeunload: sendBeacon vs img.src

Tags: javascript, http, browser, analytics, sendbeacon

In the context of a `beforeunload` handler, what is the functional difference between `fetch(keep-alive: true)` and setting the `src` attribute of an `img` tag, and which of these is the preferred method for making GET requests?

Background:

I want to send an HTTP GET request in a `beforeunload` handler in JavaScript code. `Navigator.sendBeacon`'s documentation discusses how good it is for this use case, [but](https://w3c.github.io/beacon/#introduction)

> The sendBeacon() method does not provide ability to customize the request method

Apparently there were a lot of [requests](https://github.com/w3c/beacon/issues/22) for such functionality a few years ago, which [culminated](https://github.com/w3c/beacon/pull/27#issuecomment-241549321) in the [recommendation](https://w3c.github.io/beacon/#introduction) to use `fetch()`, the browser method called internally by `sendBeacon`, with some specific flags set to solve the `unload` request problem:

> Applications that require non-default settings for such requests should use the `FETCH` API with keep-alive flag set to true

```
fetch(url, {
  method: ..., 
  body: ...,            
  headers: ...,       
  credentials: 'include',
  mode: 'cors',
  keep-alive: true,
})
```

As far as I can tell, this type of call would be functionally equivalent to `Navigator.sendBeacon`, the key setting being `keep-alive: true`.

Apparently the HTML `<img>` tag *also* [uses `keep-alive: true`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#requests) according to the spec (emphasis mine):

> A request has an associated keepalive flag...This can be used to allow the request to outlive the environment settings object, e.g., navigator.sendBeacon and **the HTML img element set this flag**

My understanding of this documentation is that making a `GET` request on `unload` via an `img` element's `src` attribute is functionally equivalent to calling `fetch()` with `keep-alive: true`, which is *itself* functionally equivalent to calling `sendBeacon` (if `sendBeacon` could make `GET` requests).

Is this accurate?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#request-class it's `keepalive`, not `keep-alive`.

Other than that, yes. This feature was added to `fetch()` to obsolete the need for `sendBeacon()`.

Comment: What's the relation of `img.src` to `sendBeacon`, specifically regarding `keepalive` and its usefulness during page unload?

Comment: Legacy behavior that likely cannot be removed.

Comment: Sounds like you're saying that `img.src` and `sendBeacon` are indeed functionally equivalent in the context of `beforeunload` handlers. Mind explicitly confirming this and editing your answer as such?

Comment: As `img` isn't completely ratified as such, it's not clear to me it's safe to assume it will always be the same going forward.